# Python splitting/findall by regex but keep delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `21-12-20 2pm - 10pm  22-12-20 10am - 6pm  24-12-20 1pm - 10pm  28-12-20 8:05pm - 8:47pm  29-12-20 12pm - 4pm` which I want to split [edit: I am using findall to do this] into a list of dates.

I am using this regex `(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}.*?(?=\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}))` to find matches but I can't get the last one to match.

Am I on the right track or should I do it a different way?

Answer (score 2):

Use `re.findall` here, rather than a string split:

```py
inp = "21-12-20 2pm - 10pm  22-12-20 10am - 6pm  24-12-20 1pm - 10pm  28-12-20 8:05pm - 8:47pm  29-12-20 12pm - 4pm"
dates = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2} \d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})*(?:am|pm) - \d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})*(?:am|pm)', inp)
print(dates)
```

This prints:

```
['21-12-20 2pm - 10pm', '22-12-20 10am - 6pm', '24-12-20 1pm - 10pm',
 '28-12-20 8:05pm - 8:47pm', '29-12-20 12pm - 4pm']
```

If you instead really just want to extract the dates, then place a capturing group around the date in the pattern:

```
inp = "21-12-20 2pm - 10pm  22-12-20 10am - 6pm  24-12-20 1pm - 10pm  28-12-20 8:05pm - 8:47pm  29-12-20 12pm - 4pm"
dates = re.findall(r'(\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}) \d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})*(?:am|pm) - \d{1,2}(?::\d{1,2})*(?:am|pm)', inp)
print(dates)
```

This prints:

```
['21-12-20', '22-12-20', '24-12-20', '28-12-20', '29-12-20']
```

Comment: ok thanks, you miss the 28-12-20 8:05pm - 8:47pm but I can handle that :)

Answer (score 1):

Since there are 2 spaces between the dates, you can also use re.split

```
st = "21-12-20 2pm - 10pm  22-12-20 10am - 6pm  24-12-20 1pm - 10pm  28-12-20 8:05pm - 8:47pm  29-12-20 12pm - 4pm"

print(re.split(r'\s\s', st))

['21-12-20 2pm - 10pm', '22-12-20 10am - 6pm', '24-12-20 1pm - 10pm', '28-12-20 8:05pm - 8:47pm', '29-12-20 12pm - 4pm']
```

Comment: the data I'm using isn't consistent enough, at least I thought it better to use a leading date to delimit